# Variable number of Arguments in C?

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I came across a Question i.e passing Variable number of arguments to a function in C. 
The Question is in this way:

Write a function that takes a variable number of arguments representing student marks in english
and returns the number of students who scored > 90 marks.
E.g.: variableArguments(3, 20, 90, 98) returns 1. One value (98) is greater than 90.

First argument is number (arg_count) of student marks followed by "arg_count" number of arguments.
E.g.: If first argument to function is 5, total number of arguments to function will be 6 (1 + 5).

```
#include<stdarg.h>
.....
.....
int variableArguments(int arg_count, ...){
 //TODO 
  .....
  .....
  return 0;
}
```

eg:`int result=variableArguments(4,87,90,98,67);`

```
 number of arguments =4
arguments=(87,90,98,67)
```

result value should be '1' because number of arguments >90 is one

In the prototype of the function first argument is `arg_count` remaining is arguments are represented as `...` **What could be the meaning of that `...` ?**

Here in this function it is given that `arg_count` gives the number of arguments passed that we need to pass to the function while calling.
If such arguments are passed to the function, **How to access the list of arguments in the definition of function ?**

Comment: [This variadic function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) might be helpful.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not a valid dupe. That one is about passing args to another function.

Comment: @user694733 agreed. but it was a duplicate after all. thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How could this be Dupe Here I am asking about `...` and access of variables

Comment: In case you want to understand what's going on when using va_ macros here is a nice [blog](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2012/06/how-variable-argument-lists-work-in-c/) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int ff(int num, ...)
{
  va_list arguments;
  int sum = 0;
  va_start(arguments, num);
  for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
  {
    sum += va_arg(arguments, int);
  }
  va_end(arguments);

return sum;
}

//call 
printf("%d\n", ff(3, 1, 2, 3));
```

va_list contains list of arguments in ..., in loop you get access one by one va_arg(arguments, int);

Comment: Please avoid giving code only answers, explain solution instead. Also `cout` is C++ construct and this is C question.

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this, this programme will return max values from function which accepts variable no. of arguments:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int arg_count, ...)
{
  int i;
  int max, a;

  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, arg_count);

  max = va_arg(ap, int);

  for(i = 2; i <= arg_count; i++) {
    if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
      max = a;
  }

  va_end(ap);
  return max;
}

int main()
{
   int count = 5;


   printf("Max value is %d", max(count, 12, 67, 6, 7, 100));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void f(int count_arg, int *arg)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < count_arg; i++)
       cout << arg[i] << endl;
}

//call
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
f(5, a);
```

Comment: That's not a *variable argument* function. It's a function which takes *exactly* two arguments.

Comment: The question specifically asks for var args! And is also tagged C not C++.

Comment: Plus, this is C++ not C

Comment: You can can use #include <stdarg.h> and  va_list arguments;

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IvanSheigets I know this kind of passing arrays in C and in C++. But here in the question I want to know the meaning of '...' and how to access if directly numbers are passed not an array.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.